# How to show options at screen like youtube player does

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I'm building a screen and flutter where the user will visualize some data and when user user touche the screen I want to show up some options just like youtube app's player does.

For example, user is using the app in landscape orientation:
[image: User using the app in landscape orientation]

When it touches the screen I want to show some options just like that:

[image: Now the user can see what it is able to do]

What are the options to achieve this behavior in my flutter app?

Comment: Are you using Flutter web?

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the whole thing with GestureDetector

```
GestureDetector(
          behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
          onTap: () => {// show the controls},
          child: DataVisualizer(),
),
```

Be careful that using this method will also trigger the click or press method of the GestureDetector if they are tappable.